# Как выстроить блоки друг за другом, не зависимо от их количества в строке?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox, css-grid

подскажите пожалуйста как выстроить блоки друг за другом, не зависимо от их количества в строке (учитывая что у всех у них есть обертка (.flex-test)). Можно ли такое сделать флексами или css гридом ?

```css
.container.flex-test-wrap{display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap}
.flex-test{display:inline-flex;flex-wrap:wrap}
.flex-test-item{width:30vw;height:15vw;background:steelblue;margin:.5vw}
.flex-test.two .flex-test-item{background:coral} 
.flex-test.three .flex-test-item{background:lightgreen}
```

```html
 <div class="container flex-test-wrap">
  <div class="flex-test">
   <div class="flex-test-item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-test two">
   <div class="flex-test-item"></div>
   <div class="flex-test-item"></div>
   <div class="flex-test-item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-test three">
   <div class="flex-test-item"></div>
   <div class="flex-test-item"></div>
   <div class="flex-test-item"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

проще говоря, надо сделать как на картинке, не меняя структуру html
[image: проще говоря, надо сделать как на картинке, не меняя структуру html]

Comment: непонятно что хочешь сделать. конкретнее напиши.

Comment: Добавил скриншот того, как надо чтобы выглядела верстка. Реально ли css'ом структурировать блоки так, как на картинке, учитывая что блоки разного цвета имеют разных родителей

Comment: Если как на картинке с цветами да, сделали уже вам. если что-то другое там, то решение нужно другое.

Comment: ты ведь привел просто пример с цветом. как образец. но, я так понимаю там будет вовсе не цвет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, мы стали забывать про старые добрые свойства `display`: `inline` и `inline-block`.

```css
.container.flex-test-wrap {

}

.flex-test {
  display: inline;
}

.flex-test-item {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 15vw;
  background: steelblue;
  margin: .5vw;
  display: inline-block;
}

.flex-test.two .flex-test-item {
  background: coral;
}

.flex-test.three .flex-test-item {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container flex-test-wrap">
  <div class="flex-test">
    <div class="flex-test-item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-test two">
    <div class="flex-test-item"></div>
    <div class="flex-test-item"></div>
    <div class="flex-test-item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-test three">
    <div class="flex-test-item"></div>
    <div class="flex-test-item"></div>
    <div class="flex-test-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть только костылем...

```css
.container.flex-test-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}

.flex-test {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}

.flex-test-item {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 15vw;
  background: steelblue;
  margin: .5vw
}

.flex-test.two .flex-test-item {
  background: coral
}

.flex-test.three .flex-test-item {
  background: lightgreen
}


/* костыль */

.flex-test.two .flex-test-item:nth-child(1),
.flex-test.two .flex-test-item:nth-child(2),
.flex-test.three .flex-test-item:nth-child(1),
.flex-test.three .flex-test-item:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translate(31vw, -16vw);
}

.flex-test.two .flex-test-item:nth-child(3),
.flex-test.three .flex-test-item:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateX(-62vw);
}
```

```html
<div class="container flex-test-wrap">
  <div class="flex-test">
    <div class="flex-test-item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-test two">
    <div class="flex-test-item"></div>
    <div class="flex-test-item"></div>
    <div class="flex-test-item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-test three">
    <div class="flex-test-item"></div>
    <div class="flex-test-item"></div>
    <div class="flex-test-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```